# How does XCode handle #import header statements in with multiple targets?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, import, header

I have an XCode project with 2 targets (both are iPhone apps sharing 95% of the same code).
However, one module isn't "shareable"; the implementations are too different.

My solution (that is not working) was to add 2 subdirectories to my `Classes/` folder in my project directory - one for each target.  In each directory, I've placed a view controller class, called `ExampleSentencesViewController`.  Of course, each file is compiled as part of only one of the targets - I'm looking for an "automatic switching" of which implementation to use based on the target.

Inside each target's settings, I added each directory to the "Header Search Paths" setting (each path for each target).

Oddly, it only compiles for the original target.  The target I added later won't compile, claiming that I've included the same header twice (there ARE two files, to be fair).  How do I get XCode to forget about the original header??

I've tried deleting the .h files out of my project, but that does not seem to help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fully qualify the header paths in the separate implementation files, based on one of your defined search directories:

`#include <MONProject/Source/ExampleSentencesViewController.h>`

vs

`#include <MONSecondProject/Source/ExampleSentencesViewController.h>`

**update based on clarification:**

ideally, you'd create a static library for the shared code.

for a simple case... you *could* take the direct approach by populating a header in your project's root, named `ExampleSentencesViewController.h`, and populating it like so:

```
/* you must define either MON_BUILD_MON_FIRST_PROJECT or MON_BUILD_MON_SECOND_PROJECT at the target level */

#if (defined(MON_BUILD_MON_FIRST_PROJECT) && defined(MON_BUILD_MON_SECOND_PROJECT))
#error invalid configuration: you cannot specify both projects to be compiled
#elif defined(MON_BUILD_MON_FIRST_PROJECT)
/* some fully qualified path: */
#include <MONFirstProject/ExampleSentencesViewController.h>
#elif defined(MON_BUILD_MON_SECOND_PROJECT)
/* some other fully qualified path: */
#include <MONSecondProject/ExampleSentencesViewController.h>
#else
#error uh... which project are you trying to build?
#endif
```

or you could just use these defines to conditionally enable/disable the interface and implementation of the classes with duplicate names (and then just include them both in the project's declaration of:

```
/* MONFirstProject/ExampleSentencesViewController.h> */

#if defined(MON_BUILD_MON_FIRST_PROJECT)
@interface ExampleSentencesViewController : NSViewController
/* ... */
@end
#endif
```

…but this will require to include both headers in your distribution (if applicable).

some of the finer details of inclusion can vary based on how you've declared your search paths (e.g., are they recursive or not?) and whether you use copy headers build phases in your xcodeproj. maintaining both projects which share code can become messy if you've been too relaxed in your include directives, discovery options, preprocessor declarations (conditional compilation/visibility) and/or build configurations so... that's why i recommend a library for the shared bits. this conditional stuff (in the two previous examples) is error prone and doesn't evolve or scale well. doing this is also a good way to confuse other tools in the development toolkit.

in fact, i prefer this over the preprocessor (assuming you're able to distribute both classes):

```
- (UIViewController *)newViewControllerForMyAwesomeView {
    if (IsAppMONFirstProject) {
        return [[MONFirstProjectViewController alloc] init...];
    }
    else if (IsAppMONSecondProject) {
        return [[MONSecondProjectViewController alloc] init...];
    }
    else {
        assert(0 && "definitely break up your code, now that it is referenced by 3 or more projects");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

if you're merely maintaining two versions of the same title, then practices will be much different.

anyways... this *should* be enough ideas to solve your problem - you just have to determine the lesser evil.

Comment: That would work if the problem was in the ExampleSentencesViewController.m implementation file.  Unfortunately, the error occurs in another VC, the one that LOADS ExampleSentencesViewController - hence the problem - I want all the other code to be agnostic about which VC it is loading; I want that decided at compile time by the target.

Comment: Justin - I'll give you the upvote for being so thorough and giving me points to consider -- maybe I should have been clearer in my question.

I do have it working using the method you suggested - wrapping the header in #ifdef blocks.  I am hoping that there's some elegant, sexy solution out there for these class of problems.

Anyhow, I'm going to keep the question open in hope that someone will provide an idea on how it "should" be set up in situations like this -- maybe even coded differently?